# Drupal module getting disabled automatically

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

We have been seeing this for quite some time now.
There is a custom module in our project that is currently under development.
We maintain separate versions(git branches) for release candidates and development code(bleeding edge). The code for module that gets auto-disabled is currently available in bleeding edge only. 
Due to some technical constraints in our hosting platform we always have to deploy our release candidate first in to our development server(Dev) whenever we want to deploy our latest release candidate in to test server.
Very often we are seeing this issue after we deploy latest release candidate in to Dev server, then push it to test server from there, and later development version is restored in Dev server. Then we see that some modules got disabled automatically.

My assumption is that drupal is auto disabling modules when it cannot find code for a module. 
Is my assumption correct?

If "Yes", where in drupal core can I find the code that is auto-disabling missing modules?

& Is there any way I can permanently prevent drupal from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is a dependency issue. When a module is disabled that may be depended on by other modules, those modules are also disabled. So lets say your custom module is depended on by other modules. Then when you disable your module, those modules are subsequently disabled.

If you look on the modules page, you'll see what depends on your module.

Comment: No, there is no other module added as dependency for this particular custom module, and there is no other module having this custom module as a dependency.